# Somar valores em um Select (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Estou com um pequeno problema, preciso preencher uma gridView no C#, porém a minha query não está fazendo a soma de alguns valores e isso está fazendo com que o código da empresa fique repetido e com o valor "separado".

O valor que eu preciso é a soma dos 3 valores do código da empresa "X", porém os valores aparecem separados.

```
select i.empresa, i.exercicio, 
(case when c.lucrocontabil=0 then c.lucrosimples 
      when c.lucrosimples=0 then c.lucrocontabil end) as lucro
from informessocios i
left join 
(select sum(coalesce(lucrocontabil,0)) as lucrocontabil, sum(coalesce(lucrosimples,0)) as lucrosimples, empresa, exercicio from informessocios where exercicio = 2017 and (lucrocontabil > 0 or lucrosimples > 0) 
group by empresa, exercicio, lucrocontabil, lucrosimples) c on c.empresa=i.empresa and c.exercicio=i.exercicio
where c.exercicio = 2017 
group by i.empresa, i.exercicio, lucro
order by i.empresa
```

[image: Exemplo do retorno da query]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tira o `lucro` do group by, e coloca essa coluna dentro da função `Sum()`

Ficaria assim:

```
select 
    i.empresa, 
    i.exercicio, 
    Sum(case when c.lucrocontabil=0 then c.lucrosimples else c.lucrocontabil end) as lucro
from informessocios i
left join (
           select 
               sum(coalesce(lucrocontabil,0)) as lucrocontabil, 
               sum(coalesce(lucrosimples,0)) as lucrosimples, 
               empresa, 
               exercicio 
           from informessocios 
           where exercicio = 2017 
           and (lucrocontabil > 0 or lucrosimples > 0) 
group by empresa, exercicio, lucrocontabil, lucrosimples) c on c.empresa=i.empresa and c.exercicio=i.exercicio
where c.exercicio = 2017 
group by i.empresa, i.exercicio
order by i.empresa
```

Comment: Rovann, muito obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo.

Comment: Marque como resposta. Se tiver dúvidas, acesse o [Tour]